# How to decrease movement of physicsBody?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm working on `physicalbody` movement , impulse applied to `physicsBody` for move body, this is my code:

```
const CGFloat ballSpeed = 5;
#define DEGREES_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)

node.physicsBody.restitution = 1.0f;
const CGFloat angle = DEGREES_RADIANS((float)rand() / RAND_MAX * 360);
const CGVector velocity = CGVectorMake(cos(angle)*ballSpeed, sin(angle)*ballSpeed);
[node.physicsBody applyImpulse:velocity atPoint:CGPointMake(0, 30)];
```

i use this code to increase speed of body.

now my problem is to decrease speed of body, How i Decrease speed ?

i tried to decrease `ballSpeed` value but its not working.

OR Is that possible to push body instead of increasing in speed ?

Comment: Apply a force which opposes the current motion to the body with `applyForce`, or use the `linearDamping` property?  Some [documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/angularVelocity).

Comment: increasing force doesn't affect movement of body.

Comment: That's pretty remarkable!  It's a strange physics engine in which applying a force to a body doesn't affect its movement.  You've got me stumped there. :-)

Comment: When i apply force Like : 
    [obj applyForce:CGVectorMake(200, 300)]; its working
 but when i increase in speed like     [obj applyForce:CGVectorMake(400, 600)];
its not working.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use vector_float3 values instead of CGFloat for physics calculations?

Comment: What are you trying to simulate?